# How to remove an item from a resultset in CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp, orm, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

I'd like to remove some specified items from a ResultSet
which means I need a ResultSet object at end.

Is there any way to remove an item from a ResultSet or create another ResultSet from existing ResultSet?

I've tried using filter() or reject().
But, they don't return a ResultSet object?

```
$ids = [123, 234, 456];
$results = $this->find()
             ->where(['xxx' => 'xxxx'])
             ->all();

$newResults = $results->filter(function ($result) {
    return in_array($result->id, $ids);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would question whether you actually *need* a result set, that is an object that implements [**`\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface`**](https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/class-Cake.Datasource.ResultSetInterface.html).

The result set interface is just a combination of `\Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface`, [**`\Countable`**](https://www.php.net/countable), and [**`\Serializable`**](https://www.php.net/serializable), which is almost satisfied by CakePHPs regular collection class, ie `\Cake\Collection\Collection`, it's just lacking `\Countable::count()`. So the collection returned by your `filter()` call should satisfy your needs in most cases.

If for some reason you'd be forced to pass a `\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface` implementation, and you absolutely cannot change that contract for whatever reason, then you could always pass your data to a new result set decorator:

```php
$resultSet = new \Cake\Datasource\ResultSetDecorator($collection->toArray());
```

Also you can manipulate your data on query level, either by simply not retrieving the data that you don't want in the first place, ie exclude them in your `where()` conditions, or by filtering in [**a result formatter**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-calculated-fields), then you'll directly receive a reduced `\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface` object from your query:

```php
$results = $this
    ->find()
    ->where(['xxx' => 'xxxx'])
    ->formatResults(function (\Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface $results) {
        return $results->filter(/* ... */);
    })
    // ...
```

Comment: A ResultSet object given from Controller is used in a template including of count()..
And I just didn't want to revise the template.
Now, I've decided to create a new ResultSet from an array. Thank you for your advice.